# Check if binary string can be partitioned such that each partition is a power of 5

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I recently came across this question - **Given a binary string, check if we can partition/split the string into 0..n parts such that each part is a power of 5. Return the minimum number of splits, if it can be done.**

Examples would be:

```
input = "101101" - returns 1, as the string can be split once to form "101" and "101",as 101= 5^1.
input = "1111101" - returns 0, as the string itself is 5^3.
input = "100"- returns -1, as it can't be split into power(s) of 5.
```

I came up with this recursive algorithm:

1. Check if the string itself is a power of 5. if yes, return 0
2. Else, iterate over the string character by character, checking at every point if the number seen so far is a power of 5. If yes, add 1 to split count and check the rest of the string recursively for powers of 5 starting from step 1.
3. return the minimum number of splits seen so far.

I implemented the above algo in Java. I believe it works alright, but it's a straightforward recursive solution. Can this be solved using dynamic programming to improve the run time?

The code is below:

```
public int partition(String inp){
    if(inp==null || inp.length()==0)
        return 0;
    return partition(inp,inp.length(),0);
}
public int partition(String inp,int len,int index){
    if(len==index)
        return 0;
    if(isPowerOfFive(inp,index))
        return 0;
    long sub=0;
    int count = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=index;i<len;++i){
        sub = sub*2 +(inp.charAt(i)-'0');
        if(isPowerOfFive(sub))
            count = Math.min(count,1+partition(inp,len,i+1));
    }
    return count;
}
```

Helper functions:

```
public boolean isPowerOfFive(String inp,int index){
    long sub = 0;
    for(int i=index;i<inp.length();++i){
        sub = sub*2 +(inp.charAt(i)-'0');
    }
    return isPowerOfFive(sub);
}

public boolean isPowerOfFive(long val){
    if(val==0)
        return true;
    if(val==1)
        return false;
    while(val>1){
        if(val%5 != 0)
            return false;
        val = val/5;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is constraint on input length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is simple improvements that can be done:

- Calculate all powers of 5 before start, so you could do checks faster.
- Stop split input string if the number of splits is already greater than in the best split you've already done.

Here is my solution using these ideas:

```
public static List<String> powers = new ArrayList<String>();
public static int bestSplit = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // input string (5^5, 5^1, 5^10)
    String inp = "110000110101101100101010000001011111001";
    // calc all powers of 5 that fits in given string
    for (int pow = 1; ; ++pow) {
        String powStr = Long.toBinaryString((long) Math.pow(5, pow));
        if (powStr.length() <= inp.length()) { // can be fit in input string
            powers.add(powStr);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    Collections.reverse(powers); // simple heuristics, sort powers in decreasing order
    // do simple recursive split
    split(inp, 0, -1);
    // print result
    if (bestSplit == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.println(-1);
    } else {
        System.out.println(bestSplit);
    }
}

public static void split(String inp, int start, int depth) {
    if (depth >= bestSplit) {
        return; // can't do better split
    }
    if (start == inp.length()) { // perfect split
        bestSplit = depth;
        return;
    }
    for (String pow : powers) {
        if (inp.startsWith(pow, start)) {
            split(inp, start + pow.length(), depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

I also found another approach which looks like very fast one.

1. Calculate all powers of 5 whose string representation is shorter than `input` string. Save those strings in `powers` array.
2. For every string `power` from `powers` array: if `power` is substring of `input` then save its `start` and `end` indexes into the `edges` array (array of tuples).
3. Now we just need to find shortest path from index `0` to index `input.length()` by edges from the `edges` array. Every edge has the same weight, so the shortest path can be found very fast with [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).
4. The number of edges in the shortest path found is exactly what you need -- minimum number of splits of the input string.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calculating all possible substrings, you can check the binary representation of the powers of 5 in search of a common pattern. Using something like:

```
bc <<< "obase=2; for(i = 1; i < 40; i++) 5^i"
```

You get:

5<sup>1</sup> = **101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>2</sup> = 1**1001**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>3</sup> = 1111**101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>4</sup> = 10011**10001**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>5</sup> = 110000110**101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>6</sup> = 1111010000**1001**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>7</sup> = 10011000100101**101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>8</sup> = 1011111010111**100001**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>9</sup> = 111011100110101100**101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>10</sup> = 10010101000000101111**1001**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>11</sup> = 10111010010000111011011**101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>12</sup> = 11101000110101001010010**10001**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>13</sup> = 1001000110000100111001110010**101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>14</sup> = 10110101111001100010000011110**1001**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>15</sup> = 11100011010111111010100100110001**101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>16</sup> = 1000111000011011110010011011111**1000001**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>17</sup> = 1011000110100010101111000010111011000**101**<sub>2</sub>
5<sup>18</sup> = 11011110000010110110101100111010011101**1001**<sub>2</sub>
...
5<sup>29</sup> = 10100001100011110000011111010111001101101011100100001011111001010**101**<sub>2</sub>

As you can see, odd powers of 5 always ends with `101` and even powers of 5 ends with the pattern `10+1` (where `+` means one or more occurrences).

You could put your input string in a trie and then iterate over it identifying the `10+1` pattern, once you have a match, evaluate it to check if is not a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to save the value for a given string in a map. For example having if you have a string ending like this: (each letter may be a string of arbitrary size)

```
ABCD
```

You find that part `A mod 5` is ok, so you try again for `BCD`, but find that `B mod 5` is also ok, same for `C` and `D` as well as `CD` together. Now you should have the following results cached:

```
C -> 0
D -> 0
CD -> 0
BCD -> 1  # split B/CD is the best
```

But you're not finished with `ABCD` - you find that `AB mod 5` is ok, so you check the resulting `CD` - it's already in the cache and you don't have to process it from the beginning.

In practice you just need to cache answers from `partition()` - either for the actual string or for the `(string, start, length)` tuple. Which one is better depends on how many repeating sequences you have and whether it's faster to compare the contents, or just indexes.

Comment: I believe the solution I provided works top-down, but to cache the result, I've to adopt a bottom-up approach right?

Comment: I don't think it matters here - the problem is exactly the same whichever way you start. You can avoid deep recurrent call stack if you do bottom-up, which is good for performance. bottom-up is the classic dynamic programming, top-down is more of an opportunistic caching. Both should result in the same cache here.

Answer (score 0):

Given below is a solution in C++. Using dynamic programming I am considering all the possible splits and saving the best results.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
int isPowerOfFive(ll n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    ll temp = (ll)(log(n)/log(5));
    ll t = round(pow(5,temp));
    if(t == n)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
ll solve(string s) 
{
    vector<ll> dp(s.length()+1);
    for(int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++)
    {
        dp[i] = INT_MAX;
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if( s[j-1] == '0')
            {
                continue;
            }
            ll num = stoll(s.substr(j-1, i-j+1), nullptr, 2);
            if(isPowerOfFive(num))
            {
                dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[j-1]+1);
            }
        }
    }
    if(dp[s.length()] == INT_MAX)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return dp[s.length()];
    }
}
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    cout<<solve(s);
}
```